# XCode Simulator is very slow

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm just starting developing with Xcode, and I tried to do an Hello World.

When I run it, Simulator opens, but it is really slow. At first it showed me the loading circle on the iPhone, then a black screen. I thought it wasn't working so I closed the app.

But, then, I tried to wait, and after maybe 3-4 minutes, the iPhone 15 Pro finally worked. And when I click or try to do something with the iPhone, it is very slow. Also my Mac start to make a lot of noises when I try to simulate the iPhone 15 Pro. So maybe it is my Mac, which is an Intel MacBook Air from 2020, but I don't think so, it's weird it cannot simulate iOS 17 no ?

So if someone has a solution I will take it with pleasure. Oh and also sorry if my English is bad, I'm French and not fluent...

Thanks.

Comment: You have an iPhone 15 simulator on an Intel Mac? You are likely pushing the minimum requirements  your app needs to be very efficient.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

Comment: Try using the Activity Monitor App to figure out what is making it so slow. MacBook Airs are under-powered for development, both in terms of CPU speed and memory. My bet is memory is the limiting factor and your Mac is "thrashing". You also might try targeting an older iOS version and smaller device like an iPhone 11. The memory requirements should be slightly less. (might be grasping at straws.)

Comment: I'm using Xcode 15 on a 2018 Intel MacBook Pro w/ macOS 13.5.2. I just ran my large app on an iPhone 15 Pro simulator. It seems maybe a tiny bit slower than older versions but it's quite usable. And no noises coming from my MacBook Pro while running the app on the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple : it's slow so you will need to buy new Mac.
I'm surprise no one thought about this answer cause it's true.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the first time you use a new simulator device, including when an iOS or macOS version has changed, it uses a lot of CPU. If you have an activity monitor running then you will see that it is very loaded. My guess is that it is performing lots of startup tasks on the simulator, such as Spotlight indexing. So this is bound to impact performance.

If the CPU load is heavy in this way, then after you have performed a simulator test you can just kill the simulator window. This also kills the load. It might happen again the next time you run the simulator, but sooner or later, it seems to complete the tasks that it needs to get done and the CPU load is low.

To accelerate the process, it may help to go into the settings on the simulator device and disable Spotlight and/or Siri. But it is tedious to do this on every device, so I usually just let it get finished over time.